# YUV Overlay in SlimDX / DirectX?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, directx, yuv, slimdx

I decode a video file using ffmpeg and once decoded I get a YUV image.
How can I display this YUV image as an overlay to a surface (or texture ?) using SlimDX / DirectX ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an offscreen with color format YUV.
get a pointer to the offscrren with lockBits.
copy the data from the ffmpeg buffers to the offscreen buffer.
release the lock.
using the device->stretchRect method to copy your image to the required position in your surface.